# Include Amazon RDS endpoint in Node JS error: An identifier or keyword cannot immediately follow a numeric literal

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I was trying to connect my Node JS application with Amazon RDS following this tutorial [Adding Node JS to RDS application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-nodejs.rds.html#nodejs-rds-connect), in my case I have the following:

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: process.env.factsDB.abcdefg.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com,
    user: process.env.johnDoe,
    password: process.env.password123,
    port: process.env.3306,
    database: 'factsDB',
    debug: false
});
```

However it gave me the following error:

```
An identifier or keyword cannot immediately follow a numeric literal
```

at `rds` at the `host`, and another error

```
',' expected
```

at `env.3306` at `port`, any idea how to fix these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `process.env` in the link provided is used to read **environmental variables**. However, from what I understand, you provide your db details directly into `createPool`.

Thus you can try the following:

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: "factsDB.abcdefg.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
    user: "johnDoe",
    password: "password123",
    port: 3306,
    database: 'factsDB',
    debug: false
});
```